# How to set CListCtrl cell color?

Tags: c++, mfc

Without customizing a new class inherited from `CListCtrl`, I created the object `m_table` with `CListCtrl`. How can I change the text color of the currently inserted data?

Below is my code block:

```
void CClassView::OnCustomdrawMyList(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    NMLVCUSTOMDRAW* pLVCD = reinterpret_cast<NMLVCUSTOMDRAW*>(pNMHDR);

    *pResult = 0;

    if (CDDS_PREPAINT == pLVCD->nmcd.dwDrawStage)
    {
        *pResult = CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
    }
    else if (CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT == pLVCD->nmcd.dwDrawStage)
    {
        COLORREF crText;

        if ((pLVCD->nmcd.dwItemSpec % 3) == 0)
            crText = RGB(255, 0, 0);
        else if ((pLVCD->nmcd.dwItemSpec % 3) == 1)
            crText = RGB(0, 255, 0);
        else
            crText = RGB(128, 128, 255);

        int nItemIndex = static_cast<int>(pLVCD->nmcd.dwItemSpec);
        int nSubItemIndex = static_cast<int>(pLVCD->iSubItem);

        CString strValue = m_table2.GetItemText(nItemIndex, nSubItemIndex);


        if (strValue == _T("F"))
        {
            pLVCD->clrText = RGB(255, 0, 0);
        }

        pLVCD->clrText = crText;
        *pResult = CDRF_DODEFAULT;
    }
}
```

I tried to get the index of the current insertion position in the `OnCustomdrawMyList` function, get the data by the index, compare the obtained data with the expected to change the color.  But this did not succeed.

Comment: If you want to set cell colors, I'd use a different class, such as [CMFCPropertyGridControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcpropertygridctrl-class?view=msvc-170), or [The Ultimate Grid](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20183/The-Ultimate-Grid-Home-Page). These support cell colors directly, so you don't need to do full custom drawing just to set a cell's text color.

Comment: I recommend you to use `CMFCListCtrl` that comes right out of the pack for this. It is derived from the normal `CListCtrl`, so you can derive your own new class from  `CMFCListCtrl` and almost all of the behaviour of your already existing list control will be there. I've done color customizations myself on this way. 
As this list as by itself methods you can override for setting background and text color, depending on the cell you are, the work is almost all already done for you.

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question a little bit? It's not quite clear what exactly is not working. You can't change the color of the list items or you can't obtain the data correctly? The last paragraph especially is quite confusing: "current insertion position" (what is exactly?), "get the data by the index" (which data and by which index?), and compare them with the "expected" ones to change the color... not quite obvious to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the Text in a subitem, then you must handle more draw states.
Also you must not return `CDRF_DODEFAULT` Appropriate is `CDRF_NOTIFYSUBITEMDRAW` or `CDRF_NEWFONT`.

```
void CClassView::OnCustomdrawMyList(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
   LPNMCUSTOMDRAW pNMCD = reinterpret_cast<LPNMCUSTOMDRAW>(pNMHDR);

  //for this notification, the structure is actually a
  // NMLVCUSTOMDRAW that tells you what's going on with the custom
  // draw action. So, we'll need to cast the generic pNMHDR pointer.
  LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW  lplvcd = (LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW)pNMHDR;

  switch (lplvcd->nmcd.dwDrawStage)
  {
  case CDDS_PREPAINT:
    *pResult = CDRF_NOTIFYSUBITEMDRAW;  // ask for subitem notifications.
    break;

    case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
    *pResult = CDRF_NOTIFYSUBITEMDRAW;  // ask for subitem notifications.
    break;

 case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT | CDDS_SUBITEM: // recd when CDRF_NOTIFYSUBITEMDRAW is returned in response to CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT.
    *pResult = CDRF_DODEFAULT;          

    :       
    :
    COLORREF clrBk  = afxGlobalData.clrWindow;
    COLORREF clrTxt = afxGlobalData.clrWindowText;
    
    if (condition)
    {
        clrTxt = WHITE;
        clrBk  = BLUE;
    }

    lplvcd->clrTextBk = clrBk;
    lplvcd->clrText = clrTxt;

    *pResult = CDRF_NEWFONT;
 // *pResult = CDRF_NOTIFYSUBITEMDRAW;
    break;
} //  CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT | CDDS_SUBITEM

case CDDS_ITEMPOSTPAINT:
    lplvcd->clrTextBk = RED;
    break;
default:                               // it wasn't a notification that was interesting to us.
    *pResult = CDRF_DODEFAULT;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this allowed me to find a solution. I solved the problem by overloading the OnGetCellTextColor method in CMFCListCtrl.

Comment: @BenAffleck maybe add your own answer too then?

Comment: Since the question is asking for a solution using the `CListCtrl`, using `CMFCListCtrl`'s facilities is not an answer. Far more useful feedback would be whether this proposed answer solves the issue.